# Unmanaged Module Error in Console

Tags: apostrophe-cms

This error came out on my console when I configured pieces in same database name using `apos.singleton` , but I managed to delete directly from DB itself using $unset method :

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
HEY DEVELOPER: the following types exist in your aposDocs collection,
but are not managed by any module. A generic manager is being stubbed in
for each one to keep your site from crashing, but you should remove thesepermanently from the database OR manage them properly by:

* Listing them as "types" for "apostrophe-pages", OR
* Providing an appropriate subclass of apostrophe-pieces.

portfolios, tryComment, trycomment

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

> This happen everytime I restart node app.

Is it not fully removed from database ? Perhaps in trash ?  I use this code to remove unmanaged pieces directly :

```
self.addTask('delete', 'Delete Query MongoDB', function (apos, argv, callback) {
  let req = self.apos.tasks.getAReq()
  return self.apos.docs.db.update({}, {
    $unset: {
      someDate: 1
    }
  }, {
    multi: true
  }, callback)
})
```

### My real question is , how to remove that error completely everytime I restart `node app` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using `$unset` to unset the `someDate` property, which is not related to this issue.

The issue is that you still have docs in your `aposDocs` collection which have the `type` property set to `portfolios`, `tryComment`, or `trycomment`.

Assuming you really want them gone, you can remove them this way (mongo shell example):

`db.aposDocs.remove({ type: { $in: [ 'portfolios, 'tryComment', 'trycomment' ] } });`

`$unset` has nothing to do with removing documents. It unsets particular properties of documents that remain in the database.